# Kotlin: isAssignableFrom and reflection type checks

Tags: reflection, kotlin

In Kotlin (1.0.6), through reflection I need to iterate over the members of a class (let's call it `Foo`), and do something based on the return type. I can write the following, which works:

```
Foo::class.members{ m ->
    if(Integer.TYPE.isAssignableFrom(m.returnType.javaType as Class<*>)){
        //do something here
    } else if ...
}
```

the problem is that the `if` statement (to handle `kotlin.Int`) is quite ugly. Is there any better way in Kotlin to achieve the same result without having to rely directly on the Java API?

Answer (score 2):

No, there is not a better way pre-1.1 Kotlin.

You can use `Int::class.javaObjectType` instead of `Integer.TYPE` to avoid using `java.lang.Integer` in Kotlin code but that makes the statement even longer (although more idiomatic).

In Kotlin 1.1 you can use [`isSubtypeOf`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect.full/is-subtype-of.html#issubtypeof) or query [`jvmErasure`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect.jvm/jvm-erasure.html).[`allSupertypes`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect.full/all-supertypes.html#allsupertypes) directly.

Comment: thx. unfortunately, I cannot try 1.1, as it does not seem available yet on Maven Central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-maven-plugin/) Once it will be available, I will try it out, and see how that ``if`` statement can be simplified with ``isSubtypeOf``